# How to resolve 'Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed' issue

Tags: sql, foreign-keys

I am trying to create a database table called `wp_tokens` with a foreign key relationship to another table called `wp_users`. However, every time I attempt to run the create table SQL, I get the error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed". I have tried multiple re-edits of the same code, but I just cannot figure out what is going on.

This is the code for `wp_users`

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_users` (
    `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_login` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_pass` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_nicename` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_registered` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `user_activation_key` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `display_name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    KEY `user_login_key` (`user_login`),
    KEY `user_nicename` (`user_nicename`),
    KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 
COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This is the SQL for `wp_tokens`

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_tokens` (
    id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
    `token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users (`ID`)
)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `unsigned` is important -- the types need to be identical.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_tokens` (
      id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `user_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `token` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (id),
      FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wp_users (`ID`)
)
```

[Here](https://rextester.com/QVVYD56562) is a rextester.

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I missed that! Thanks, I'll accept yours as the answer

Comment: I missed it too. Upvoting.